# Why do I get "InvalidNameIdPolicyException: MSIS7070" when authenticating via ADFS?

Tags: saml, adfs

I am trying to set up ADFS authentication (Server 2012) to a Bomgar appliance. Both ADFS and Bomgar are running in VMware Workstation virtual machines. ADFS is acting as the IdP (located at https://wodan-kaveh.ingi.local), and Bomgar is the Relying Party (located at https://cenhelm). Everything is resolving in the Windows HOSTS right now as this is a demo environment.

I've imported the Relying Party metadata from Bomgar to ADFS and the FederationMetadata.xml from ADFS to Bomgar. Bomgar successfully refers the browser to the ADFS login page, I can successfully authenticate with my AD users there, and the browser is successfully referred back to Bomgar from the ADFS login page; however, at that point, I receive an authentication failure message from the Bomgar login form, ADFS logs Event ID 364, and the SAML Message Decoder for Chrome logs a StatusCode value of "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy".

The ADFS error indicates that NameIDPolicy is not satisfied. Question 16403359 over on stackoverflow had an answer pointing out this line in ADFS event log: "Actual NameID properties: null."; however, the NameID in my ADFS Relying Party Trusts config is populated. I can see this under the "Identifiers" tab of the trust config for Bomgar.

Does anyone with ADFS experience know about this null NameID / InvalidNameIDPolicy problem?

### ADFS Event ID 364

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
https://cenhelm 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.InvalidNameIdPolicyException: MSIS7070: The SAML request contained a NameIDPolicy that was not satisfied by the issued token. Requested NameIDPolicy: AllowCreate: True Format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent SPNameQualifier: . Actual NameID properties: null.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

### SAML Message Decoder output

```
# 3 - SAMLResponse via post binding, at 2016-09-28 18:45:14.920Z (UTC)
<samlp :Response ID="_5c2e83d2-dad5-45e8-ad6f-061dade744fd"
       Version="2.0"
       IssueInstant="2016-09-28T18:45:14.837Z"
       Destination="https://cenhelm/saml/sso"
       Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
       InResponseTo="BG_0658b1fe7ad38b90b836fda526fc1853bd76485b"
       xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://WODAN-KAVEH.ingi.local/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
  <ds :Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds :CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <ds :SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <ds :Reference URI="#_5c2e83d2-dad5-45e8-ad6f-061dade744fd">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds :Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds :Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds :DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <ds:DigestValue>g5s0YwnOGbEqRgTqeJDVQxgj16OBVKixtvoESNGODPk=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>RExxLxsgjwjbOlGST9lzrwGzj/WhvIvH4ZxP1YplnHNaXjGOKZQDrkuaW78EGdwjgoTKph5iBk1R21PLxHxIKx9DL/z/wpCDhOQzyfPTv39qo3OjEATwUakiukvL98y5AypdFtUSK7BzJvjN0TqgfpJpIWj6ritf0cGeSLl3SuGxlcWwrqcAgpxyIXL15rtQk6pGgIBszSGNeeN5kTKr+Z+kZu95uFF0M7yMbObYom2BXGA9KgOmGqnadCcw80nzI3g78E0I1ZWegmgmiBbnXIfDWuLDiblrLGOg3bJNZu4yflYH5JpjHQyWI9Hg05l3yT5dxOcFaij6XNnLi2XHkQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp :StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester">
      <samlp :StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy" />
    </samlp:StatusCode>
  </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
RelayState
https://cenhelm/saml
# 2 - SAMLRequest via redirect binding, at 2016-09-28 18:45:14.797Z (UTC)
<samlp :AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
       xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
       ID="BG_0658b1fe7ad38b90b836fda526fc1853bd76485b"
       Version="2.0"
       IssueInstant="2016-09-28T18:45:01Z"
       Destination="https://wodan-kaveh.ingi.local/adfs/ls/"
       ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
       AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://cenhelm/saml/sso">
  <saml:Issuer>https://cenhelm</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp :NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
         AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
RelayState
https://cenhelm/saml
# 1 - SAMLRequest via redirect binding, at 2016-09-28 18:45:01.643Z (UTC)
<samlp :AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
       xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
       ID="BG_0658b1fe7ad38b90b836fda526fc1853bd76485b"
       Version="2.0"
       IssueInstant="2016-09-28T18:45:01Z"
       Destination="https://wodan-kaveh.ingi.local/adfs/ls/"
       ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
       AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://cenhelm/saml/sso">
  <saml:Issuer>https://cenhelm</saml:Issuer>
  <samlp :NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
         AllowCreate="true" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
RelayState
https://cenhelm/saml
SAML Message Decoder
CLEAR ALL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add "Persistent name identifier" claim rules:

1. Choose your Relying Party Trust and make a custom issuance transform rule to create unique user identifier claim.
2. Then transform persistent identifier claim into Name Identifier claim.

Detail steps by step and rule detail, you can check [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/card/2010/02/17/name-identifiers-in-saml-assertions/)

Comment: I already had a Persistent Identifier rule set up; however, after reading the article you referenced, I adjusted it to use the "Incoming claim type" of "Windows account name" instead of "ID" (which is what I had before). That worked! Thanks for your help :)